# Splitting data frame values at a specific word

Tags: python, regex

I have a column of string values:

```
df[V1]
Could you please speak a little bit more slowly
Could you please speak a little bit more slowly
Could you please speak a little bit more slowly
Could you please speak a little bit more slowly
```

I tried to use the following code but it also includes the word I want to split after:

```
split_list = re.findall(r'\bspeak.*\b', df['V1'])
```

I want to split each row at the exact same word into two columns. In this case it would be the word speak. I would like to end up with something like this:

```
df
V1                       V2
Could you please speak   a little bit more slowly
Could you please speak   a little bit more slowly
Could you please speak   a little bit more slowly
Could you please speak   a little bit more slowly
```

Comment: Try to match e.g. [`^.*\bspeak\b|\S.*`](https://regex101.com/r/eItPPw/2) or for splitting [`\s(?<=\bspeak.)\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/5MRZ05/2)

Comment: Thanks bobble bubble, I was able to use your code in a loop to get a nice list with what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that helped! :) Maybe worth to mention: If you have multiple `speak` in a line, using [*lazy* `.*?` will match up to the first](https://regex101.com/r/A6vtpM/1) VS [*greedy* `.*` to the last](https://regex101.com/r/A6vtpM/2) occurance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the regex that bobble bubble provided to answer my own question:

```
fac_list = []

for fac in list:
    test_fac = ' '.join(fac)
    y = re.findall(r'^.*\bspeak\b|\S.* ', test_fac)
    fac_list.append(y)
print(fac_list)
```